# Spark SQL Schema

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, schema

I have this RDD in PySpark and i want to make the schema.

Example of 1 row of RDD collected:

```
(('16/12/2006', '17:24:00', 4.216, 0.418, 234.84, 18.4, 0.0, 1.0, 17.0), 0)
```

```py
customSchema = StructType([
    StructField("Date", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Hour", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ActivePower", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("ReactivePower", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("Voltage", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("Instensity", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("Sub1", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("Sub2", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("Sub3", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("ID", IntegerType(), True)])
```

The problem is that the Index (last zero) is out of the tuple of data and I don't know how to make the schema correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. you just need another `StructField`:

```
data = [
    (('16/12/2006', '17:24:00', 4.216, 0.418, 234.84, 18.4, 0.0, 1.0, 17.0), 0)
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("values", StructType([
        StructField("Date", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Hour", StringType(), True),
        StructField("ActivePower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("ReactivePower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("Voltage", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("Instensity", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("Sub1", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("Sub2", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("Sub3", FloatType(), True),
    ])),
    StructField("ID", IntegerType(), True)
])


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Hour: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ActivePower: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ReactivePower: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Voltage: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Instensity: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Sub1: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Sub2: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Sub3: float (nullable = true)
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
```

```py
df.show(1, False)
```

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+---+
|values                                                    |ID |
+----------------------------------------------------------+---+
|[16/12/2006,17:24:00,4.216,0.418,234.84,18.4,0.0,1.0,17.0]|0  |
+----------------------------------------------------------+---+
```